# Is it possible to detect when a low-level keyboard hook has been automatically disconnected by Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, keyboard-hook, setwindowshookex

I am working on a program that uses keyboard hooks. However, when the PC that the program is running on is just slightly overloaded, it causes Windows to disconnect the hook from the program, causing it to no longer respond to keystrokes.

Is there a way to prevent this, or even better, propose a different way of solving the exact same problem, by using a different architecture, maybe involving a pipeline?

Comment: Which API call are you using to set up the hook?  What evidence do you have that this keyboard hook gets disconnected on its own, as you are describing?  Is this a documented issue, or does it only apply to your program?  When you consume the keyboard hook, do you handle the incoming message quickly, by putting it in a buffer or something?

Comment: @Brad: Definitely documented. Windows automatically uninstalls the hook if your app takes too long to respond. The asker has things a bit confused, though. Rather than figuring out a way to *work around* this, he needs to fix his application to be a good citizen. Fix the cause, rather than the symptom.

Comment: I can't fix the cause. My users are running complex 3D renders, disconnecting the hook. The renders consume nearly 100% of all of their possible hardware resources. There is **no way** that I can be a good citizen here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't "detect" this, and you absolutely shouldn't need to. What you're describing is a feature, specifically one introduced in Windows 7 to protect your system from rogue applications.

The [applicable documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985.aspx) describes it thusly (pay particular attention to the bolded section):

> The hook procedure should process a message in less time than the data entry specified in the `LowLevelHooksTimeout` value in the following registry key:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
> ```
>
> The value is in milliseconds. If the hook procedure times out, the system passes the message to the next hook. However, **on Windows 7 and later, the hook is silently removed without being called. There is no way for the application to know whether the hook is removed.**

The solution here is most certainly **not** to figure out a way to "detect" when the hook is uninstalled and reinstall it. You should have figured out that you're doing something wrong when the operating system uninstalled the hook the *first* time.

The actual solution is to redesign your application to return from the hook procedure more quickly. Ideally, you should return almost immediately. If you need to run some type of intensive calculation in response to the low level messages (and I can't really imagine why you would), then you should store the information you receive, return from the hook procedure, and do your processing at a later time (probably on a separate thread).

In fact, that's almost *exactly* what the documentation continues on to suggest:

> **Note:**  Debug hooks cannot track this type of low level keyboard hooks. If the application must use low level hooks, it should run the hooks on a dedicated thread that passes the work off to a worker thread and then immediately returns. In most cases where the application needs to use low level hooks, it should monitor raw input instead. This is because raw input can asynchronously monitor mouse and keyboard messages that are targeted for other threads more effectively than low level hooks can. For more information on raw input, see [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536.aspx).

Comment: The problem is that I display a Window when a specific keyboard combination is used. Now, when the CPU is under intense work, as an example rendering a 3D compilation in the background, the program fails, and the hook disconnects.

Comment: @Mathias: The important thing to note here is that returning from the hook procedure is orthogonal to your application's ability to respond to the message received in the hook procedure. You can still display the window upon receipt of that keyboard combination, you just can't delay returning from the hook procedure. As I mentioned, save the necessary information while you're in the hook proc and then return. Show the window on another thread at your and/or the computer's leisure.

Comment: Cody is correct. Create a Queue data structure, then make the sole job of the hook to enqueue an item and quit. Make a separate thread in your process read that queue and do the associated action.

Comment: Paul, even with that kind of approach, a heavy 3D render running in the background or something else breaks the hook. How can I prevent that?

Comment: @Mathias: How can that be? Windows is a pre-emptively scheduled operating system, and it takes an absolutely trivial amount of time to enqueue an item.

Comment: My clients have been running Maya simulations in 3D while it breaks. Even a simple operation such as ´Window.Show´ disconnects the hook if the PC is very busy.

Comment: Window.Show isn't trivial, it's potentially redrawing your entire window.  Something trivial is allocating some memory, assigning it to a data structure, and returning.  Anything that relies on the window manager, file I/O, or so on runs into the risk of your hook taking too long to execute.

Answer (score 4):

I am not so sure that the keyboard hook is always to blame. We all seem to agree that under ideal or average conditions everything should be responsive. But during its lifetime from startup to shutdown a hook also has to survive some worst-case scenarios. In my company we wrote some keyboard hooks, and they are as lightweight and asynchronous as possible, yet they still occasionally appear to get disconnected.

As a user, every day I type several ten-thousand characters. I reboot once a month at best, and on occasions I am guilty of skipping a Windows Update. With options like suspend and hibernate, I don't think I am alone. As a developer, I have to make sure that the hook keeps running from beginning to end, regardless of what happens to the system.

Normally my system is very responsive. But there can be brief, exceptional moments where it is on its knees to the point that even Windows Aero gets switched off. Right now it is very snappy. But if I press the Show Desktop button, the mouse will freeze for at least a second during the time that my 65 or so open windows are all collapsed. What if I press a key during one of these moment?

If Windows can freeze the mouse for one second, if Windows can even switch off Aero during a brief moment of heavy load, why can't a keyboard hook be allowed to survive a similar exceptional time of overload? Instead, because of one exceptional moment, Windows pulls the plug, silently affecting the remaining computing experience until system shutdown. For 200 ms affecting just one keypress out of the thousands we press every day, for just that fraction of a second, I, the user, have to reboot the system because that's the only way I understand will bring back the keyboard macro or whatever utility I depend on for my productive work.

Even if it was guaranteed to prevent the above (which worst-case experience seems to suggest is not the case), I am not so sure that everything can easily be done in a separate thread. For example, let's say the user sets up a hotkey that is to start an application. Couldn't there be reasons for starting the application from the current context (foreground window, privileges, etc.)? And wouldn't it be reasonable for the user to actually expect and accept a delay, because he knows that, using the keyboard, he just started something that takes longer? I don't know if the example is technically sound, but I wanted to illustrate how sometimes things that otherwise may be unacceptable could be acceptable, as a result of a known event.

Keyboard hooks can be very useful for many things, from macros to error correction to launching things, and this behavior introduced in Windows 7 is putting the good and the bad, the acceptable and the unacceptable, the average and the exceptional, all in the same basket. This hurts both users, because quality keyboard hooks may get killed, and developers. Just imagine what a support nightmare it is when you have no official solution to your application working well under normal conditions, but being killed at random under some heavy load (or other inexplicable) circumstance.

To conclude this with a question, does anyone know what the status is under Windows 8, has anything changed?

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is still in the final official Windows 8 RTM.

Answer (score 2):

Cody Gray's response is excellent, but FWIW, **and purely for testing purposes**, you may be able to detect a disconnected hook.

When your hook proc is invoked, store the current tick count in a variable accessible to the main thread. In the main thread, periodically call `GetLastInputInfo`. It will give you the tick count for the last input event in the system (not just in your process). If the value provided by `GetLastInputInfo` is significantly later (newer) than your last hook proc tick count, it's a good guess that hook has been disconnected.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks! Wow, how come I didn't think of that before?

Comment: Hi, Im having the same problem as Mathias I managed to do the GetLastInputInfo but I dont completely understand the method. I have a timer running every second and checks the current ticks and compares with the invoked one. But what happens when the user does not use the keyboard and the ticks go up more and more. Wouldn't that be a false reading? When I move my mouse around the ticks gradually go up and eventually if I do a lot of movements then the tick will reach to the point where the program thinks that its significantly later (newer) and it will trigger the Unhook/Hook again.

Comment: @Zakukashi - this will only work if you have both a keyboard *and* a mouse hook installed. That way, you get the timings for both types of events, and you don't really care about which of the two `GetLastInputInfo` returns. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some "bad-performance" code in your hook . that's the reason why makes slightly overload .

"it causes Windows to disconnect the hook from the program"

Does any error raise in your hook and you don't handle it ?

AFAIK, Windows wouldn't disconnect the hook if it works well by itself.

Comment: Windows will by default disconnect the hook if 1 keystroke takes longer than 200 ms to respond to.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing priority of the process of your application.